# Facebook SDK in combination with JSON help please

Tags: ios, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, sbjson

I've read a lot of topics about this issue. But none of them really describes my problem.

So one the solutions to solve the errors that are occuring if you combinate facebookSDK with JSON is to rename the JSON classes that are causing a conflict.

SO that is exactly what I did. I have renamed all the classes that where causing the errors (not only the filenames ;).

So now when I run my app Xcode sais: no complications, BUT I get thread 1 sigabrt.

**The whole Xcode message:**

> Couldn't register *blabla.blabla* with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
>   This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
>   (gdb)

Answer (score 2):

This xCode message is not related to your json or facebook stuff. Delete your app, restart your phone and it will get rid of it

Comment: Thanks 4 the quick respond. Just did that.

But now the build is succeeded, but still crashes (without any error now).

If I remove the references to the facebookSDK and resources.bundle it works like a charm. 

But I need those... any suggestions?

Comment: **I dont use ARC by the way**

Comment: Duplicate classes (because Facebook uses JSon as well, and I already used Json in my app).

**NOTE: I've tried facebookSDK 3.0 and 3.1 as well... still the same**

Comment: Should be able to go ahead and delete the json library out of the facebook sdk

Comment: I have solved an earlier error by using the **-all_load** linking flag. Does it has something to do with that maybe?

Comment: Yes but how? it is like a bundle with some LEGO icon. I cant see the contents of it

Comment: No it shouldnt... The thing is that your application only needs one JSON library. So delete one of them, then to ensure yours is being compiled go into targets/build phases/ compile sources and make sure all of the .m json sources are in there, add them if they are not. since you arent using arc you shouldnt have to change any compiler settings

Comment: another option is to go here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/src and manually add all of the facebook files to your project into a folder, and make sure they are added to your compile sources

Comment: OKay thank you very much. I will restore to a previous snapshot and try your latest suggestion. I will get back ya.  

..after friends/dinner ;).

Comment: unfortunately it didnt worked out, because:

I've downloaded the package as a zip file, but it turns out to be the 3.1 sdk. BUT I dont have the newest Xcode (because I dont use lion) and so I dont have the newest frameworks (like social).

Very annoying.. I need a zip of the facebook 3.0 src